# I am using jqgrid 4.6.0. Unable to get the available column/Add Column on columnchooser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want the column chooser like: I have tried in fiddle, couldnt complete. new to fiddle.

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WorkingColumnChooser.htm

```
Please help.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nagarajputhiyavan/yNw3C/13180/

Comment: just search in Google for videos about the usage of JSFiddle (like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBhOrml6qxQ)). The GUI is changes a little in the last versions of JSFiddle, but the main idea stay unchanged. One can add any JavaScript library in "External resources" see on the left part. If you find [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) not simple enough, then you can use [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/), [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/), [CodePen](http://codepen.io/), [LiveWeave](http://liveweave.com/) or other.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example on ok-soft, you need to initialize the grid pager before you can add your button to it.

Add the following code before you add your column chooser button.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
```

Note that you are also loading the javascript files in an incorrect order. The mutli select file should be loaded before jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

- include `jquery-ui.min.js`
- include `ui.multiselect.js`
- include `ui.multiselect.css`
- include `jquery-ui.css`

add new button which calls the column chooser

```
var grid = $('#list');
grid.jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#pager',
             {   caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                 title: "Choose Columns",
                 onClickButton: function() {
                      grid.jqGrid('columnChooser');
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did few workarounds in your sample fiddle, now it's working fine - [**Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/yNw3C/13190/). I'm loading local data directly since you haven't explained your constraints.

> - Make sure your `json` data looks like following local data.
> - As well `multiselect` plugin loads first before jqgrid.

Following is modified code of grid,

```
var data = [{ id: "111",  thingy: "Test", blank: "N/A", number: "100",  status: "active"},
            { id: "112",  thingy: "Testing 123", blank: "N/A", number: "20",  status: "Inactive"},
            { id: "200",  thingy: "My data", blank: "N/A", number: "80",  status: "Inactive"}];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: data,
    height: 250,
    pager: '#pager',
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60 },
    {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90 },
    {
        name: 'blank',
        index: 'blank',
        width: 50},
    {
        name: 'number',
        index: 'number',
        width: 80 },
    {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 80 }
    ],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
    // ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}
});

$("#grid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
$("#grid").jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
    title: "Choose Columns",
      onClickButton: function () {
        $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
      }
});
```

Your grid and column chooser looks like below,

[image: Grid with column chooser]